# get the `top 4 products from each toptier category sorted by date-added (to bigcommerce)`

Tags: handlebars.js, bigcommerce

*BigCommerce Stencil*

I totally winged the below snippet. But i need a hint on doing that the correct way. I basically need to get the `top 4 products from each toptier category sorted by date-added (to bigcommerce)`

```
    {{#each categories}}
      {{#each products sort:date-added limit:4}}
        {{name}}
      {{/each}}
    {{/each}}
```

Answer (score 0):

To add, the syntax I would use is the following. However, I don't have any evidence that such a way exists yet.

home.html

```
{{> components/product/all-products grid=products.all default_image=theme_settings.default_image}}'
```

all-products.html being a custom file.

all-products.html

```
{{#if grid}}
  <section class="products-new {{theme_settings.background-for-new-products}}">
    <div class="layout-container">
      <h1 class="section-title">{{lang 'product.product_blocks.new_products.heading'}}</h1>

      <div class="product-grid">
        {{#each grid}}
          {{> components/product/product-item this show_quickshop=true show_rating=true default_image=../default_image}}
        {{/each}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
{{/if}}
```